# Re-activation of vim-youcompleteme

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, linux-debian

I recently had an 'rm -rf' related mishap in my home directory ( Ubuntu 14.04 installation ).

Vim ( v 7.4.52 ) and the add-on package 'vim-youcompleteme' had been installed prior to the mishap and worked perfectly .

After recovering from my goof-up, I noticed that the completion features from 'vim-youcompleteme' no longer seemed to be working.

I tried complete removal of the package ( apt-get purge vim-youcompleteme ) and subsequent re-installation, hoping that this would reinstate the aforementioned add-on package and its capabilities. This didn't help.

I suspect something in the resource / settings data must have gotten corrupted.

I am hoping for suggestions that would lead to the resurrection of the completion feature for Vim.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The addon packages in Debian/Ubuntu are typically managed using the [vim-addon-manager](https://packages.debian.org/stable/vim-addon-manager) package.

Once an addon package is installed, you run `vam install <addon>` to enable it in your user's config.  In this case, you likely want to run `vam install youcompleteme` but `vam list` can confirm the addon name.

Comment: Hi there @jamessan. thanks for your solution. It worked ...and I learned something new about this very important tool we use ( Vim ).